Human readable acess to member function
Due to the lack of reflection in current C++, I found myself writing the following JSONDUMP() macro for data debugging:
struct Vector {
    float x, y;

    float len() const;

    JSONDUMP(x, y)
};

As its name suggests what JSONDUMP() does is to enable converting the object automatically into a JSON object. It uses the C preprocessor to generate pairs ("field", field) and then implements a JSONObject jsonDump() const member function using these pairs. The pair generation macro looks like this:
#define JSONDUMP_PAIR(x) (STRINGIFY(x), (x))

and JSONDUMP() would be something like:
#define JSONDUMP(...) \
JSONObject jsonDump() const { \
    return JsonObjectSerializer() JSONDUMP_GENERATE_PAIRS(__VA_ARGS__); \
}

where JsonObjectSerializer is a class that implements operator() to add key-value pairs to the JSON object being generated.

I'm omitting the implementation of JSONDUMP_GENERATE_PAIRS() since it is not the crux of the issue here. That macro just maps a list of items into a list of calls to the JSONDUMP_PAIR() macro, i.e. JSONDUMP_GENERATE_PAIRS(a,b,c) is expanded to JSONDUMP_PAIR(a)JSONDUMP_PAIR(b)JSONDUMP_PAIR(c).

This works fine, no biggie.
The issue arises when someone wants to include in the serialization member functions that represent properties of the object, such as len() in the example:
struct Vector {
    float x, y;

    float len() const;

    JSONDUMP(x, y, len) <-- C++ not happy with that
};

Since the pairs are expanded inside the definition of a member function I have access to the members (that's why ("x", (x)) expansion for member variables works in the first place), so what I eventually did was to write the member function with parenthesis (i.e. invoking it in the context of the expanded jsonDump() implementation) and removing the parenthesis from the expanded member name by parsing them:
struct Vector {
    float x, y;

    float len() const;

    JSONDUMP(x, y, len()) <-- This works
};

I think this syntax was succinct enough to do the job, but I'm not particularly happy with having to rely on parsing and string manipulation to workaround the () issue.
I was wondering if there's any technique (Preprocessor based or others) that allows invoking member functions referencing them by name only so that I could just write JSONDUMP(x, y, z, len).

Do not reinvent the wheel. There lots of JSon libraries which do this out of the box. For example nlohmann json

std::invoke(&Vector::len, this) does the right thing, but I don't know how you can get at Vector from inside the macro...

More often than not, trying to make magical code to reduce typing effort results in a whole lot of bulky code that is hard to maintain and debug, and ties you to a design that's less resilient to changes in requirements. It's always tempting to pursue this stuff, but sometimes the simplest, most unimaginative code is best. I've been bitten in the ass by clever code so many times, that I hope one day I'll learn to follow my own advice.

So many people have tried to add "properties" and "reflection" to C++ already. It is not part of the language and adding Macros to the mix is not making things better. What you end up doing is adding "accidental" complexity (complexity that will not add to any functional requirements). As said there is at least one very good json library out there (nlohman/json). Use that and you can get the help of a large community of other users too and focus on the parts of your code that matter. (Learning how to reuse tested libraries is a good thing to do too)

I think OPs question is a valid variation on the theme. The nlohmann_json serialization expands to nlohmann_json_j["len"] = nlohmann_json_t.len, whereas they wanted = nlohmann_json_t.len()

I got it to work with this unholy abomination:
#define JSONDUMP_PAIR(fld) #fld, ([this]() { \
  using THIS = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*this)>; \
  return std::invoke(&THIS::fld, this); \
})()

This works because std::invoke is happy with both a member field pointer and a zero-argument member function pointer.
The only catch was getting the type of this so we use a local type definition for that. The entire thing is wrapped in an IIFE because we need actual statements.
EDIT: the IIFE is actually not necessary:
#define JSONDUMP_PAIR(fld) #fld, \
  std::invoke( \
    &std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*this)>::fld, \
    this)

but it will not win any beauty or maintainability prizes.

Heh, that's clever. When trying different options I went with writing the member pointer instead of member() but ditched it because I didn't like it (too verbose). I didn't think about deducing the class name. I''ll leave the question open for a while to see if someone finds another alternative (I'm curious) but I think we have a winner here.

Of course in your approach you can move the derivation of THIS to the body of JSONDUMP and keep JSONDUMP_PAIR as just the std::invoke call.
